# jquery vertical carousel slash slider

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

Hello so I ve been trying to find a carousel that is vertically aligned. Everything I keep finding is a carousel with 1 image but slides vertically the idea is like 3 or more images that are aligned vertically not horizontally and an arrow on the top to slide up and another on the bottom. any suggestions please

Answer (score 0):

I finally found one http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php very simple so it can be customized however you want it!